# My authorization on website with android does not working

Tags: android, authorization, jsoup

My authorization on website with android does not working. I first investigated the requests for the site using the Chrome console.

On the web page `https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/` there is an authorization window. I filled in the login and password fields and clicked "Sign in". Chrome console info:

**?next=/diary/**

**General**

Request `URL:https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/`
   Request Method:POST
   Status Code:302 FOUND
   Remote Address:94......
   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
   Cache-Control:max-age=0
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
   Date:Sun, 14 May 2017 17:59:37 GMT
   Expires:Sun, 14 May 2017 17:59:38 GMT
   Last-Modified:Sun, 14 May 2017 17:59:38 GMT
   Location:`https://school.proServer.ru/diary/`
   ...

**Request Headers**

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
...
   Referer:`https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/`

Form Data

csrfmiddlewaretoken:nybZEyn8GhJWV4om8TFx1uXK4iRebjKl

index_page_view-current_step:auth

auth-username:myusername

auth-password:mypassword

**Next page in Console**

**diary/**

**General** 
   Request URL:`https://school.proServer.ru/diary/`
   Request Method:GET
   Status Code:200 OK
   Remote Address:94.41.0.7:443
   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
   Set-Cookie:...

**Request Headers**
   Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   Cache-Control:max-age=0
   Connection:keep-alive
   Cookie:...

My code (I get a token):

```
 try {

 Connection.Response res1 = Jsoup.connect("https://school.proServer.ru")
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36")
     .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
     .data("next", "/diary/")
     .method(Connection.Method.GET)
     .execute();
 Document welcomePage = res1.parse();
 welcomCookies = res1.cookies();
 Element input = welcomePage.select("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").first();

 token = input.attr("value");

 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 System.out.println("token " + token);
 System.out.println("welcomCookies " + welcomCookies.toString());
```

And my authorization:

```
try {

 Connection.Response res = Jsoup
     .connect("https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/")
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36")
     .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
     .followRedirects(true)
     .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
     .timeout(7000)
     .data("auth-username", log)
     .data("auth-password", pass)
     .data("index_page_view-current_step", "auth")
     .data("csrfmiddlewaretoken", token)
     .method(Connection.Method.POST)
     .cookies(welcomCookies)
     .execute();

 System.out.println(res.url());

 }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

Error occurs:

> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403,
>   URL=https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/

Please help me!

Comment: maybe `next=/diary/` has to be encoded?

Comment: How to do it? How to correct the request?

Comment: `"https://school.proServer.ru/?next=" + URLEncoder.encode("/diary/", "UTF-8")`

Comment: again error: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=school.ufanet.ru/?next=%252Fdiary%252F

Comment: then it themes like you can't access that URL from your mobile device. Have you tried opening it in device browser?

Comment: i solved problem! )

Answer (score 0):

Some of the websites do not work if “referer” header is not sent along with the request. You may get HTTP 403 error while accessing those websites using Jsoup, since Jsoup pass empty value for the “referer” header by default.

To set referrer or “referer” header, you can use referrer method of Connection class. My solution - add line in authorization:

```
.referrer("https://school.proServer.ru/?next=/diary/")
```